# Using EntityFramework for Visual FoxPro

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core, visual-foxpro

I need to make a scaffold operation to generate my Models .NET CORE with EntityFramework for local file .DBC of Visual Fox Pro 9.0. It is possible?

Comment: What's the backstory here? (The short answer is "no, you can't" because FoxPro was killed-off over 15 years ago and never supported essential RDBMS features that EF/EFCore depends on - the long answer is that given that some brave (or foolhardy?) soul has already attempted to build a FoxPro provider for EFCore  which looks like it should work, you may-as-well give it a try https://github.com/tombrothers/EntityFrameworkCore.Vfp - but I'd question your sanity before you continue...)

Comment: ...my sanity... I have a customer that I ask me a syncronization with old project that he needs to maintain live...so I need to found a solution!!!
I have already take a look at this framework, but there is no documentation about how to use it, in particolar if I can use it for scaffold or not...

Comment: Yes you can. Try using Tom Brother's EF provider. https://github.com/tombrothers/EntityFrameworkCore.Vfp

Comment: For some documentation check https://github.com/tombrothers/VfpEntityFrameworkProvider2 and https://tombrothers.wordpress.com/test. If I remember right he also had scaffolding support for his LinqToVFP project (you could do the scaffolding in code yourself too).

On the other hand, you might simply use VFPOLEDB without EF. It is simple and easy.

Comment: @Dai what essential RDBMS features does it not support that EFCore would rely on ?

Comment: @AlanB The ability to run on currently-suported versions of Windows Server for one...

Comment: @Dai Runs perfectly well on every version of Windows server up to and including Server 2022,  just like any other 32-bit application. Also that wouldn't be an RDBMS feature.#